# Django manytomany object_set query by field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have ManyToMany field in model and i want to query it from another model which has _set field by default:

```
class Airport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    airports = models.ManyToManyField(Airport)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

So query like:

```
a=Agents.objects.filter(airports_name_contains='asd')
```

works fine. But:

```
b=Airport.objects.filter(agent_set__name__contains='agent_')
```

gives

> Cannot resolve keyword `'agent_set_name'` into field

I want to query exactly `Airport` model. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops, my bad. I found solution. Django representaion of manytomany field shows "agent_set" in the lookup, but the field itself is "agent":

```
agents=Airport.objects.filter(agent_name_contains='agent_')
```